# How to use servlet as controller?

Tags: servlets

I am developing an application regarding automation . In that I am planned to use JSP for web page designs, Servlets as controller.

How to use servlet as controller? Plz help me for this question. If any other solution is there, then just suggest me, I'll change it.

Comment: Once you have create a servlet(all config and java file), just don't generate output from servlet, use this servlet for redirecting user to different view, that will make it a controller.

Comment: @Arvind: +1. But I think you mean "forward" not "redirect" (the latter sounds like an extra HTTP roundtrip by-passing the controller).

Comment: Refer to the servlets info page on this site, which explains how to do it: http://stackoverflow.com/tags/servlets/info